# Cordova : Android icon not showing

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to add Icon to a codrova project for Android.

What ever i do , the icons dont seem to show up on the Android device.

I have tried the following in my config.xml

```
 <platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/logo.9.png" />

  </platform>
```

Also tried :

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/logo.9.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/logo.9.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/logo.9.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/logo.9.png" density="xhdpi" />
  </platform>
```

All i get is a empty icon . I have checked my PNG file , its fine.

I am using VS 2015 Update 3 for Cordova tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to include these images. also could you rename your files to be something like this: logo9.png. and try to build and deploy to a device to check this out. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I have created a video to show step by step how to package android apps to google store. check it out: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MostafaElzoghbi/Packaging-Cordova-Apps-to-Google-Store

Comment: removing the dot did the trick . logo9.jpg works . Why is that ?

Comment: because it became an invalid file name. glad this answered your issue.

Comment: Thanks . Will this illegeal file name appear as a warning somewhere ? ( build log maybe ? )  It would help in debugging apps on VS

Comment: I will take this note to the product team. Feel free @Pat to reach out to me with any issue you may have.